# Include an unnumbered appendix chapter in TOC and hide numbered appendices from TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, appendices

I have a few appendices that I do not want to show in the TOC. Instead, in the TOC, I want a single entry named "AllAppendices" to be shown. This shall be an (unnumbered) chapter in the appendix. The real appendices shall be (numbered) chapters, but again, not in the TOC.

These two versions I have tried:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
%\renewcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}\refstepcounter{chapter}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

I want to be able to reference FirstAppendix: \ref{FirstAppendix}, \nameref{FirstAppendix}
\chapter{LastRealChapter}
\label{LastRealChapter}
\chapter*{AllAppendices (can be added to TOC manually)}
\appendix
\label{AllAppendices}
\cleardoublepage
\tocless
\chapter{FirstAppendix (numbered, but not in TOC)}
\label{FirstAppendix}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this:

- `nameref` never works correctly, it references "AllAppendices"
- `ref` works in the second version, but not in the first
- I get a warning in the second version: "destination with the same identifier (name{appendix.A}) has been already used, duplicate ignored"

So my questions are:

- How to do it properly?
- What are the implications of `\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}\refstepcounter{chapter}`?

The MWE can be simplified:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
\renewcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}\refstepcounter{chapter}}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    I want to be able to reference Appendix like this: \ref{Appendix}, \nameref{Appendix}
    \chapter*{SomethingElse}
    \cleardoublepage
    \appendix
    \tocless\chapter{Appendix (numbered, but not in TOC)}
    \label{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Commenting out the `\cleardoublepage` seems to help, at least for `\ref`.

Edit: And it does work in my document. So is the bottom line "no `\cleardoublepage` before `\tocless` chapters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need complicated patches. Just insert in the `.toc` file at suitable location a change to the `tocdepth` counter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

% added in edit: (hyperref takes into account the current value
% of tocdepth, it was set to -3 during execution of \tableofcontents
% hence we must reset it; alternative: the option bookmarksdepth
% of hyperref -- see its documentation in the README of hyperref !)

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % (downto subsections)

% 
\vspace{1cm} 

I want to be able to reference FirstAppendix: \ref{FirstAppendix},
\nameref{FirstAppendix} as well as SecondAppendix: \ref{SecondAppendix},
\nameref{SecondAppendix}.


\chapter{LastRealChapter}
\label{LastRealChapter}
\appendix

\chapter*{AllAppendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{AllAppendices}


\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-3}}

\chapter{FirstAppendix (numbered, but not in TOC)}
\label{FirstAppendix}


\chapter{SecondAppendix (numbered, but not in TOC)}
\label{SecondAppendix}
\end{document}
```

[image: table of contents]

Comment: Perfect! Hadn't thought of this. It also works to reset the counter after my appendices (there are some declarations following the appendix that again I want to appear in the TOC). 

Note that I need to use `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{...}}` because I have a `\usepackage{calc}` in my document, which clashes with your originally proposed solution.

Comment: @bers glad it helped and that you could fix the impact of package `calc` on `\setcounter`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following lines in the preamble makes all the things you want automatic:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
\def\@schapter#1{%
  \begingroup
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{\Hy@chapapp*}%
    \Hy@raisedlink{%
      \hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend
    }%
  \endgroup
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\H@old@schapter{#1}%
}
\def\Hy@org@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
      \fi
   \fi
   \chaptermark{#1}%
   \if@twocolumn
     \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
   \else
     \@makechapterhead{#2}%
     \@afterheading
   \fi}
}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
\def\@schapter#1{%
  \begingroup
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{\Hy@chapapp*}%
    \Hy@raisedlink{%
      \hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend
    }%
  \endgroup
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\H@old@schapter{#1}%
}
\def\Hy@org@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
      \fi
   \fi
   \chaptermark{#1}%
   \if@twocolumn
     \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
   \else
     \@makechapterhead{#2}%
     \@afterheading
   \fi}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace*{5cm}
I want to be able to reference FirstAppendix: \ref{FirstAppendix}, \nameref{FirstAppendix}
\chapter{LastRealChapter}
\label{LastRealChapter}
\appendix
\chapter*{AllAppendices (can be added to TOC manually)}
\label{AllAppendices}
\chapter{FirstAppendix (numbered, but not in TOC)}
\label{FirstAppendix}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It does work, even in my 120 pages, 40 packages document. However, the answer by @jfbu, though later, is so much more straightforward. Thanks anyway!